# Nestjs @Sse : return result of a promise in rxjs observable

Tags: rxjs, nestjs, server-sent-events

I am trying to go a simple step beyond the [nest doc example](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/server-sent-events#usage) in implementing @Sse() in a controller but I never used rxjs untill now so Im a bit confused.

The flow is :

1. client send a `POST` request with a file payload
2. server (hopefully) sends back the newly created `project` with a prop `status:UPLOADED`
3. client subscribe to sse route described below passing as param the `projectId` it just received from server
4. in the meantime server is `doingSomeStuff` that could take from 10sec to a min. When `doingSomeStuff` is done, project status is updated in db from `UPLOADED` to `PARSED`

My need is for the @Sse decorated function to execute at x interval of time a "status-check" and return `project.status` (that may or may not have been updated at the time)

My present code :

```
  @Sse('sse/:projectId')
  sse(@Param('projectId') projectId: string): Observable<any> {
    const projId$ = from(this.projectService.find(projectId)).pipe(
      map((p) => ({
        data: {
          status: p.status,
        },
      })),
    );
    return interval(1000).pipe(switchMap(() => projId$));
  }
```

I don't put code of the service here as it a simple `mongooseModel.findById` wrapper.

My problem is the status returned remains `UPLOADED` and is never updated. It doesnt seem the promise is reexecuted at every tick. If I console.log inside my service I can see my log being printed only once with the initial `project` value while I expect to see a new log at each tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a two-step process.

1. We create an observable out of the promise generated by `this.service.findById()` using the `from` operator in rxjs. We also use the `map` operator to set the format of the object we need when someone subscribes to this observable.
2. We want to return this observable every x seconds. `interval(x)` creates an observable that emits a value after every `x` milliseconds. Hence, we use this and then `switchMap` to the `projId$` whenever the interval emits a value. The `switchMap` operator switches to the inner observable whenever the outer observable emits a value.

**Please note:** Since your server may take 10 sec, to min for doing the operation, you should set the `intervalValue` accordingly. In the code snippet below, I've set it to 10,000 milli seconds which is 10 seconds.

```js
const intervalValue = 10000;

@Sse('sse/:projectId')
sse(@Param('projectId') projectId: string): Observable < any > {
  return interval(intervalValue).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.projectService.find(projectId)),
    map((p) => ({
      data: {
        status: p.status,
      }
    })));
}


// OR

@Sse('sse/:projectId')
sse(@Param('projectId') projectId: string): Observable < any > {
  const projId$ = defer(() => this.service.findById(projectId)).pipe(
    map(() => ({
      data: {
        _: projectId
      }
    }))
  );

  return interval(intervalValue).pipe(switchMap(() => projId$));
}
```

Comment: Very clear, works like a charm... added the return `project` inside `map` anon function param to access the return value and do `map((p) => ({  data: { _: p.anyProperty  }   }))` and that's seems to do the trick. Thx. Just to be sure : at each 'tick' of the interval, `findById` gets reexecuted and the returned value is the result of the new promise, not the same result returned every time ?

Comment: That's correct. At each tick of the interval, the findById will re-execute. The switch map is forcing it to switch to the `findById` observable on each tick.

Comment: Sorry I "unresolve" the question as it does'nt seem to work after further implem. I edited my initial question.

Comment: @Pierre_T Have edited the answer. Please verify now and let me know if it works.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without explicit interval? I Just want to send event to client when some data is fetched, but nextjs force us to use Observeble which is annoying

Comment: very clear and useful answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

@softmarshmallow
You can watch model changes and use observable stream to send it.
Something like this

```js
import { Controller, Param, Sse } from '@nestjs/common'
import { filter, map, Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs'

@Controller('project')
export class ProjectStatusController {
  private project$ = new Subject()

  // watch model event
  // this method should be called when project is changed
  onProjectChange(project) {
    this.project$.next(project)
  }

  @Sse('sse/:projectId')
  sse(@Param('projectId') projectId: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.project$.pipe(
      filter((project) => project.projectId === projectId),
      map((project) => ({
        data: {
          status: project.status,
        },
      })),
    )
  }
}
```